# Android SDK retrieve files of specific version

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have downloaded SDK in SDK standalone manager.
I have downloaded the complete api from **2.2 to 6.0 all files nearly 64GB**.
I want to give sdk to my friend only of marshmallow or any specific version.
Please help me how can i retrive specific version files

Answer (score 0):

Go to your SDK folder

Then platform -> android-23 copy and share with your friend

android-23 is marshmallow

android-22 is lollipop 5.0.2

and so on..

Comment: I wanna share API and system images files too?

Comment: Then in sdk folder copy platform tools , extras and tools

Comment: If i m copying only platform.What about other files